# Linebreak before URL with biblatex/alphabetic

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

Using biblatex with alphabetic style, **how could I insert a line break** (\\ or \linebreak) **before the URL output** (with the aim to have less linebreaks within URL)?
(I use url and hyperref)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=red!50!black]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{formaturl}{\newline #1}
\newbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
\printtext[formaturl]{%
  \printfield{url}}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext[urldate]{\printurldate}}}

\begin{document}
\cite{ctan}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With  `DeclaredFieldFormat` you can format the whole string of url and urldate. In this case I insert a `\newline` in front of the ouput.

EDIT:

added `printtext`

[image]

Comment: thanks, it adds a line.. but it changes the text style, before it was kind of verbatim and now it's like the rest of the text.. How come?

Comment: @JohannesL: Now it works ;-)

Comment: I also found a version were it works (in my output, the URL wasn't colored anyway)

Comment: @JohannesL: I used `colorlinks=true` to demonstrate a link. The boxes around a link are not printed.

Comment: If `url` is not specified for an entry, this adds a new line and a period (the end marker of the url field?). Adding a surrounding `\iffieldundef{url}{}{...}` fixes this.

Comment: For me it now shows the "visited on..." thing twice, like
(visited on [visited on 01/15/2021])

Answer (score 2):

I found the following package useful for line breaking an URL. At the preamble, just put `\usepackage{breakurl}` somewhere after `\usepackage{hyperref}`. The `\burl` command is defined and, by default, the package also turns the `\url` command into a synonym of `\burl`.

Comment: This allows breaks _within_ the url, it does not make the url start on a new line as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution is to just redefine the corresponding field format. I would replace the `\space` after "URL" with a `\nobreakspace` instead of explicitly adding a line break. This allows TeX to decide if a line break is the best solution. (I recommend setting the bibliography `\raggedright` in order to give TeX some more wiggle room here.)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\nobreakspace\url{#1}}
```

---

If you really want the explicit `\newline`, you can of course do that as well. I would still keep the `\nobreakspace` in order to avoid "URL" being on a line by itself.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\newline\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\nobreakspace\url{#1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>This was posted by OP as an edit to the question, but it's clearly an answer.</sup>

Slightly enhancing @Marco's original answer:

If it should be totally like in the original but with a line break, use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\newline\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\newbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
 \printfield[url]{url}%   
 \iffieldundef{urlyear}     
 {}     
 {\setunit*{\addspace}%      
 \printtext[urldate]{\printurldate}}}
```