# biblatex and new line for DOI, URL and Eprint

Tags: biblatex

I've been playing around with biblatex a little and, since I am tired of broken DOIs, URLS and other eprint links, I would like to use a biblatex style which implements a new line for these fields. I started from the `standard.bbx` file and in the article style, I replaced

```
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}
```

by

```
\newline
\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}
```

There is something wrong since a dot (.) is added at the beginning of the DOI line in the final bibliography and a new line is added even though the doi field is empty. Is there a way to fix this?

Then, I wanted to go a bit further by having a new line for each of the DOI, URL, EPRINT, then something like:

```
\newline
\usebibmacro{doi}
\newline
\usebibmacro{url}
\newline
\usebibmacro{eprint}
```

by replacing `\newbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}` by `\newbibmacro*{doi}`, `\newbibmacro*{eprint}` and `\newbibmacro*{url}` (copy-paste process of the last lines of `standard.bbx`) and by replacing `\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}` by the lines above but unfortunately, it does not work. I'd be happy to hear from you on this.

Comment: A [previous answer by Marco](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27953) offers an alternative approach that edits the URL format.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`\setunit` is an alternative to `\newunit` that allows you to set punctuation instead of `\newunitpunct` (which is typically a period plus a space). The really neat thing about `\newunit` and `\setunit` is that you don't need to worry about generating excessive punctuation, particularly when some fields are missing.

The code below defines a new bibliography macro `bbx:parunit`. It issues `\setunit` to generate line breaks only in the bibliography. With the option setting `backref=true`, `bbx:parunit` also prints the back reference immediately before the first line break. Edits are applied to generic bibliography macros from `biblatex.def` so that the solution should work with most styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backref=true]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:parunit}{%
  \ifbibliography
    {\setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
     \usebibmacro{pageref}%
     \clearlist{pageref}%
     \setunit{\adddot\par\nobreak}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:parunit}% Added
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{eprint}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:parunit}% Added
  \iffieldundef{eprinttype}
    {\printfield{eprint}}
    {\printfield[eprint:\strfield{eprinttype}]{eprint}}}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:parunit}% Added
  \printfield{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext[urldate]{\printurldate}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
Filler text.\footcite{bertram,kastenholz,ctan,itzhaki}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's very nice but now, `\footcite` is a bit too long. I think that `\footcite` with the author, the year and the title + a numeric link to the full biblio at the end of the document (the way numeric style works now but the link [1] would be embedded in the `\footcite`) would be the best compromise.

Comment: Nice again and clearly usable. You think it is possible to control/reduce what is in the footnotes by keeping what is in the main references? Something like: Initials and family names for the authors; title; year; journal and no more? That'd be great !

Comment: @pluton It is definitely possible, but I'd open that up as a new question as that problem is very style-specific and separate from your original question.

Comment: I do not know now since your solution is very nice. I was thinking of the usual `style=numeric` and \footcite{ref1} (your first reference) would provide as a footnote : `A. Bertram &  R. Wentworth, "Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces", J. Amer. Math. Soc (1996) [1]` and the [1] would be linked to the full citation at the end organised by the usual numeric style, but that's just an idea.

Comment: about your very last comment, I'll open a new question as soon as possible. Many thanks!

Comment: One little more thing here is that the `backref` page will be indicated after the last of the doi, eprint and url fields and it looks odd. Also, redefining `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{page = {p\adddot},pages = {p\adddot}}` has no effect.

Comment: @pluton I've updated to solution to print back references before `doi`/`eprint`/`url`. This solution should not change the behaviour of any bibliography strings. Inserting your string redefinition has the expected result on my end - the page reference for Bertram & Wentworth changes from `pp.` to `p.`.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you could write a user guide : Biblatex by example :) Strange, I do not get the p. and pp. I'll try to figure out why.

Comment: Got it. The `abbreviate=false` option does not like the `pp.` and `p.` redefinition, that's unfortunate.

Comment: @pluton Good to hear you've figured out the problem. I'm actually not convinced a user guide on top of the `biblatex` documentation is necessary. The manual has many examples and there are sample `tex` files to get you started. Style files are well-organized so it easy to look under the hood to see how everything works. If the documentation isn't enough (or is maybe too much?), lockstep's posts on this site are pretty good at flattening that initial learning curve.

Comment: Hmm, it prints `(visited on [visited on 03/24/2012]).` for me

Comment: Got it... instead of `\printtext[urldate]{\printurldate}` use `\printtext{\printurldate}`

Answer (score 9):

You can't directly include `\newline` in the `.bbx` file as it is 'text' and will be out of position in the `biblatex` tracker. Instead, you need to use the `\printtext` macro

```
\printtext{\newline}%
\usebibmacro{doi}%
\printtext{\newline}%
\usebibmacro{url}%
\printtext{\newline}%
\usebibmacro{eprint}%
```

I'd probably make this a bit more sophisticated, and use `\iffieldundef` to conditionally include these new lines

```
\iffieldundef{doi}
  {}
  {%
    \printtext{\newline}%
    \usebibmacro{doi}%
  }%
```

Comment: Thanks. Sounds promising. And the `{doi+eprint+url}` environment could be redefined separately as `\newbibmacro*{doi}{\iftoggle{bbx:doi}{\printfield{doi}}{}}` plus the same for `eprint` and `url`?

Comment: I am not sure why Audrey removed the provided answer?

Comment: @pluton It had bug I wanted to fix. The post is back now.