# customized \footcite command

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

Based on an answer on [new line for doi eprint url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29802/biblatex-and-new-line-for-doi-url-and-eprint) in the bibliography with biblatex, a question arose on the possible use of the `\footcite` command with the provided new style. This `\footcite` command seems to be a good compromise for rather long scripts where you do not want to disturb the main text with things like [Author Year] (authoryear style) or when you want to provide more information than [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29802/biblatex-and-new-line-for-doi-url-and-eprint)] (numeric style). So, the question is how to create a personal biblatex style based on the numeric style that would provide information in a footnote when `\footcite` is used. Minimal information here should be thought for each case `@article`, `@book`, `@phdthesis`, `@inproceedings` but would just indicate contracted author names, title, year... The link to the main reference in the bibliography section should be added as well in the footnote.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can define a new citation command based on `\footcite` under the `numeric` style and the generic citation commands `\citeauthor`, `\citetitle` and `\citeyear`. How all the entry information is ordered and delimited is up to you. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}

% Adapted from \footcite in numeric.cbx and generic citation
% commands \citeauthor, \citetitle, \citeyear in biblatex.def
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footpartcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
   \setunit{\addnbspace}
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
   \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
   \newunit
   \printfield{year}}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footpartcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\footpartcite}{\addsemicolon\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
Filler text.\footpartcite{bertram}
Filler text.\footpartcites(See)(for example){markey}[10--15]{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can it be modified to print conference/journal as well?