# How to replace the second footcite "Author. Title. Year." by "Ibid"?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I would like to present footcites as follow:

> Author. Title of the article. Year of the article. [ref]

or

> Ibid. [ref] (for the second times of the same cite)

For the first presentation, I use a new Cite command defined from [customized \footcite command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29922/customized-footcite-command).

Here's some code for testing purposes:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Aggarwal2004b,
author = {Aggarwal, B. B. and Takada, Y. and Oommen, O. V.},
journal = {Expert Opin Investig Drugs},
month = oct,
number = {10},
pages = {1327--1338},
publisher = {Informa Pharma Science},
title = {{From chemoprevention to chemotherapy: common targets and common goals}},
volume = {13},
year = {2004}
}
\end{filecontents}    
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[autolang=hyphen,backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[bookmarks,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footpartcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
   \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
   \newunit
   \printfield{year}
   {\adddot}
   \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footpartcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\footpartcite} {\addsemicolon\space}

\bibliography{mybib} 
\begin{document}

Test~\footpartcite{Aggarwal2004b}. \\
Test~\footpartcite{Aggarwal2004b}. \\
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

But, this doesn't replace the footcite by "Ibid. [ref]" if the footcite is already in the document.

The result is:

> [image: Result]

The result should be like this:

> 1 Aggarwal, Takada, and Oommen. “From chemoprevention to chemotherapy: common
>   targets and common goals”. 2004. [ref].
>
> 2 Ibid. [ref].

Is there any solution to replace the second footcite by Ibid...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, the only thing we have to do is to tell `biblatex` we want to be able to track "ibid" by `ibidtracker=constrict` (or any other option that turns on the `ibidtracker`, see p. 56 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for more on that, `constrict` is the `authoryaer` standard setting).

In our new cite command we then only need to check whether the citation was cited before (and whether it is not the first citation on a new page) and if so, print "ibid" instead of the whole stuff

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footpartcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:fullpartcite}}%
   \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
   \printtext[brackets]{%
     \usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

where `cite:ibid` prints "ibid" and is defined as follows

```
\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}
```

and `cite:fullpartcite` prints the more verbose citation

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:fullpartcite}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{year}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[autolang=hyphen,backend=biber,style=numeric,ibidtracker=constrict]{biblatex}
\usepackage[bookmarks,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}
\newbibmacro*{cite:fullpartcite}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{year}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footpartcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:fullpartcite}}%
   \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
   \printtext[brackets]{%
     \usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footpartcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\footpartcite}{\addsemicolon\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\begin{document}

Test\footpartcite{wilde,baez/article}.

Test\footpartcite{cicero} again \footpartcite{cicero}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be great if the citation is still **Ibid. [ref]** on other pages after the first full citation. I've tried to suppress '\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage' but it's the full citation on a new page. A solution ?

Comment: @asl If I delete the `\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage` I do get "ibid" for subsequent citations even if they are the first on the page. You will *not* get "ibid" if you do `\cite{wilde}\cite{cicero}\cite{wilde}`, as "ibid" essentially means: "The exact citation before." Maybe you want something like `\ifciteseen` instead of `\ifciteibid`? But then the "ibid" string is highly inappropriate.

Comment: You're right. In this case, "ibid" string is inappropriate. So, I will change the string. But, if I replace `\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage` by `\ifciteseen`I have no "ibid" and the next citation is a full citation. What it's wrong ?

Comment: @asl You will have to issue `citetracker=context` in order for the citetracker to work (analogous to `ibidtracker=constrict` which you now will not need anymore as you don't use `\ifciteibid`).

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for; many thanks!