# Footnotes numbered, with reference number and short reference text

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing, footnotes

For my thesis I need a special citation style:

- all footnotes have to be numbered ascending
- after the footnote number the reference number has to be printed in brackets
- then the real citation should be printed

[image]

Currently I am using biber/biblatex and citestyle "authortitle" in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, 
style=authoryear-icomp,%% Zitierstil mit Autorennamen + Jahr (Langversion)
citestyle=authortitle,
bibencoding=utf8,
natbib=true, %% Bereitstellen von natbib-kompatiblen Zitierkommandos
hyperref=true, %% hyperref-Paket verwenden, um Links zu erstellen
backref=true, %% Seiten anzeigen, auf denen die Referenz vorkommt
block=space, %% kleiner horizontaler Platz zwischen den Feldern
isbn=false, %% ISBN nicht anzeigen, gleiches geht mit nahezu allen anderen Feldern
url=false, %% Url-Feld wird ausgeblendet. Ausnahme: Online-Typ
pagetracker=true, %% ebd. bei wiederholten Angaben (false=ausgeschaltet, page=Seite, spread=Doppelseite, true=automatisch)
%refsegment=chapter, %% Arbeitet mit optionalen Referenzen die als Segmente am Ende eines Kapitels eingefügt werden (statt: refsection).
%refsection=chapter % benutze automatisch Kapitel als Bibliographie-Abschnitt
citetracker=true % Wird benötigt für kapitelweise Referenzen?
]{biblatex}


% Fußnoten sollen Autoren aufnehmen können.
\usepackage{xpatch}
```

using the autocite command to create the footnote:

```
TEST \autocite[][10]{KitchenhamStuartGuideline2007}
```

[image]

Comment: Like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29922/customized-footcite-command

Comment: How should the bibliography be sorted? How are the numbers in brackets determined? The screenshot does not suggest alphabetic sorting by author (K->L->Q->E).

Comment: Did DG's link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29922/customized-footcite-command help you? If not, what exactly needs to be changed for the answer to satisfy your needs?