# biblatex -- short citation style

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am trying to modify the citation style of `biblatex` for a `beamer` presentation. Using [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29922/customized-footcite-command/29931#29931) and [this follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461307/biblatex-custom-citation-with-conditional-clause) of mine, I have used the resulting code (see MWE below) happily for some time, which yields the following output:

[image]

While working on a new talk, I have decided that I want a different (shorter) citation style that should look like this:

[image: Wanted short style]

with "author, journal **journal volume**, pages (year)".

Is there a way to achieve this? I have tried to use the same tricks as for the journal name to get the journal volume, but I get `! Package biblatex Error: Bibliography macro 'volume' undefined.`

Could there even be a predefined `citation-style`? I appreciate any kind of ideas.

MWE (note: the `documentclass` in this MWE is `article`, not `beamer`, since it does not impact the behaviour in this case):

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                              

\usepackage{filecontents}                                                                                            
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}                                                                                        
@article{article,                                                                                                    
author = {Vimes, Samuel},                                                                                        
title = {The Influence of Species Diversity in the City Watch},                                                  
journal = {Unseen University Non-Magical Journal},                                                               
volume  = {4}, 
pages = {42--37},                                                                                                 
date = {1988}                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
\end{filecontents}                                                                                                   

\usepackage[backend=biber,maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=2,                                                              
giveninits=true]{biblatex}                                                                                           
\addbibresource{bib.bib}                                                                                               


% previous citation style                                                                                            
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citejournal}                                                                                    
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}                                                                                            
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%                                                                                          
    \ifentrytype{article}{\usebibmacro{journal}\addcomma\addspace}{}}                                               

  {\multicitedelim}                                                                                                  
 {\usebibmacro{postnote}}                                                                                          

\newcommand{\cfootcite}[1]{                                                                                          
  {\tiny{\citeauthor{#1}, \citetitle{#1}, \citejournal{#1}\citeyear{#1}}}} % to get author, title, journal, year     

% attempt at new style                                                                                               
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citevolume}                                                                                     
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}                                                                                            
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%                                                                                          
    \ifentrytype{article}{\usebibmacro{volume}\addcomma\addspace}{}}                                               

  {\multicitedelim}                                                                                                  
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}                                                                                           

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1\isdot}}                                                           

\newcommand{\cfootcitenew}[1]{                                                                                      

  {\tiny{\citeauthor{#1}, \citejournal{#1}\citevolume{#1}(\citeyear{#1})}}} % to get author, journal, journal number, year                                                                                                               



\begin{document}                                                                                                     

Old style:                                                                                                           

\cfootcite{article}                                                                                                  


Attempt new style:                                                                                                   

\cfootcitenew{article}

\end{document}
```

Output (while ignoring error):

[image: Full output MWE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend against lobbing together several high-level `\cite...` commands into a `\newcommand`. (In some cases this can lead to actual problems with citation tracking, but usually it is just more work than necessary.)

The usual way to do create a new citation command is to define it with `\DeclareCiteCommand`. Usually this command delegates all the hard work to a `bibmacro`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=2,
  giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\mktexttiny}[1]{{\normalsize #1}}
% the definition should of course be {{\tiny #1}},
% but \normalsize is easier to read in the MWE

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cfootcitenew}[\mktexttiny]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cfootcitenew}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{cfootcitenew}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\printfield{journaltitle}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printfield{volume}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield{pages}}
    {\printfield{labeltitle}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibparens{##1}}%
  \printdate
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@article{article,
  author  = {Vimes, Samuel},
  title   = {The Influence of Species Diversity in the City Watch},
  journal = {Unseen University Non-Magical Journal},
  volume  = {4},
  pages   = {42--37},
  date    = {1988},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cfootcitenew{article}
\end{document}
```

[image: Vimes, Unseen University Non-Magical Journal **4**, 42–37 (1988)]

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! Do you know a good tutorial/guide on how to write a new `cite` command like this? I find the `biblatex` manual more confusing than helpful...

Comment: @Taunch Sorry, I know of no good tutorial for more advanced `biblatex` programming . Currently, the best way to learn it is to look at the source (`biblatex.def`, `standard.bbx`) and imitate what it does.

Comment: I see, that is unfortunate for the intimidated (like me). Maybe I will ask a separate question for a beginner's guide.

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind: I noticed that now the full citation output in the bibliography also follows the same style. While this doesn't bother me per se, one thing does look weird: the year is now in double parenthesis ([1988]). How can this be changed?

Comment: @Taunch See the edit.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but that doesn't change anything... It's only the one line `\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibparens{##1}}%`, right?

Comment: @Taunch You also need to remove the `\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}` that was there previously.