# Avoiding inelegant splits on URLs

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, urls

I am using `biber` and `biblatex` to process my bibliography. URLs are handled with `breaklinks=true` under `hyperref`.

I have found an inelegant breakup of a hyperlink resulting in a reference like this [image: this citation]

Is there a way to enforce a more elegant breakup of a URL link where the `h` is not split from the `ttp`?

Comment: It seems that the author of **biblatex** has decided that, since URLs tend to give bad paragraphs, they should be split at any point, for the sake of good line breaking.

Comment: @egreg Looks like he changed his mind in version 1.7. Numbers and letters are no longer breakpoints by default. They can be re-introduced by setting values for the breakpoint penalties.

Comment: @Audrey Nice to know; that choice may be interesting, but the author must be allowed to choose easily between the two possibilities

Comment: From the [Biblatex release notes](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/RELEASE): _Version 1.7 adds counters
   which control the penalties associated with the additional
   breakpoints. They are disabled by default but may be helpful (as a
   last resort) if you need to deal with long and/or tricky DOIs. See
   'biburlnumpenalty' etc. in the manual for details._

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`biblatex` breaks URLs using the `url` package. Breakpoints are configured with `\biburlsetup`, discussed in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22854/4483). Version `1.7` of `biblatex` makes improvements to this command. By default it avoids breaks at lowercase letters entirely. The example below demonstrates how you could alter the breakpoint penalty for selected entries in a `category`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}

% Set low penalties for breaks at numbers, uppercase letters and lowercase letters
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{100}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{100}

% Define a category to selectively print entries with a higher lowercase penalty
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{badbreaks}
\addtocategory{badbreaks}{ctan}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifcategory{badbreaks}
    {\defcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{ctan,markey,wassenberg}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Audrey. Your solution works. I take it that the commented lines were uncommented in the original definition and that putting them in the preamble after the invocation of `biblatex` accomplishes URL non-breaks at lowercase letters. Please correct me if I have misunderstood this.

Comment: @chandra That is correct. You could prevent breaks at selected characters instead. In the code provided, for example, omitting `\do\t` from the original definition would have the same effect. Other ways to avoid dealing with breaks are to [hyperlink the title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available/23843#23843) or [insert a break before printing the URL](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29802/4483).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the two links. In my particular case, the author, via a citation note on the website, requires the URL to be cited in the bibliography, precluding hyperlinking the title, but a  break before the URL is a good alternative solution here.

Comment: It woks in footnote citation (with `\footcite{}` command) when `\AtEveryBibitem{}` is replaced with `AtEveryCitekey{}`.

Comment: Does not work for me. Setting the `\defcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{val}` directly works as expected, whereas `\AtEveryBibitem{}` does not.