# Biblatex breakline Doi

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

I'm using the XeTeX with BibLaTeX and biber. 
That's the line:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authortitle-ibid]{biblatex}
```

It's working fine but I'e just get one problem with one of the DOI as you can see. The "x" on the last line looks quite stupid. How can I avoid it?

[image: Example of the problem]

Comment: Not a real solution to the problem, but a good workaround: use a short DOI: http://shortdoi.org/10.1046/j.1365-2648.1998.00768.x

Answer (score 8):

"Stupid"-looking breaks in URLs are sometimes tough to avoid. From [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22871/4483), you can see that the break penalty at a period (along with other symbols) is given by `\UrlBreakPenalty`. To avoid breaks at these symbols for a particular set of entries `<key1,key2,...>`, you can adapt a [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30863/4483) and add the following code to your preamble.

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{badbreaks}
\addtocategory{badbreaks}{<key1,key2,...>}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifcategory{badbreaks}
    {\mathchardef\UrlBreakPenalty=10000\relax}
    {}}
```

This will reset the break penalty locally from `200` to `10000` before printing any entry in the `badbreaks` category.