# Achieve Linebreak in DOI in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, xetex, line-breaking, doi

In my references (using XeLaTeX, `biblatex` and Biber) I have one specific DOI that is hanging over more than a centimeter after line-break.

All other DOI are correctly wrapped. Even inserting a (wrong space in the DOI does not help at all). How can I fix that?

I invoke `biblatex` using:

```
 \usepackage[safeinputenc,uniquelist=false,maxnames=2,%
             minnames=1,maxbibnames=99,style=authoryear,url=false,%
             dashed=false,firstinits=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

and `hyperref` sign:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfa,pdfencoding=auto,pdfusetitle,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

P.S.: I know I can use: 
 `\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100}`
but I'd prefer to perform a manual linebreak using some trick

Comment: I have to point out that the linebreaks in my bibliography are not clean at all. Even in the author field.

Comment: Have ever thought about setting your bibliography with ragged right margin instead of justified? This would allow LaTeX to just put the whole DOI into a new line and as the bibliography is no continuous text it would be acceptable from a typographic point of view to do different than in the text itself.

Comment: You can reset the break penalty for specific bibliography entries. Examples can be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30863/4483 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51139/4483

Comment: @Benedikt . Nice Idea! How do I set the justification of the bibliography. Changing the maring of komascript or by biblatex parameters?

Comment: @Audrey I dislike to change parameters since my guess is that the person who set them has had a reason to change them and things have rarely improved when I changed default setting. Thus, I'd prefer to add hard linebreaks.

Comment: @louiscypher The penalties were created to allow the user to change them. The default values at number and letters are high, so overfull boxes with these characters are common.

Comment: @louiscypher: to do this just put the command that triggers the output of your bibliography into a group together with a ``\raggedright`` command: ``{\raggedright \printbibliography}``

Comment: @Audrey Works fine for urls. But what is the name of the penalties used for names? I cannot find anything in the documentation that works (tested high/lownamepenalty). BTW: are these values reset in new referencesections?

Comment: @louiscypher Breaks in name parts are controlled by the `lownamepenalty` and `highnamepenalty` counters. Details can be found in `biblatex.def`. These penalties default to no more than `\hyphenpenalty`, which is normally very low. None of the penalties are reset. For URLs definitions are hooked into `\bibsetup` and `\citesetup`. Other penalties are defined globally.

Comment: @Audrey could you make this an answer?

Comment: Workaround: Use a short DOI: http://shortdoi.org/10.1108/01439910810876427

Answer (score 2):

Audrey wrote the comment:

---

> You can reset the break penalty for specific bibliography entries.
>   Examples can be found here: [Avoiding inelegant splits on URLs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30857/avoiding-inelegant-splits-on-urls) and  [Biblatex breakline Doi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51127/biblatex-breakline-doi)

---

> Breaks in name parts are controlled by the `lownamepenalty` and
>   `highnamepenalty` counters. Details can be found in `biblatex.def`.
>   These penalties default to no more than `\hyphenpenalty`, which is
>   normally very low. None of the penalties are reset. For URLs
>   definitions are hooked into `\bibsetup` and `\citesetup`. Other
>   penalties are defined globally.