# How can I enforce a line-break of DOIs in the references?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, line-breaking, doi

In my bibliography four items extend beyond the column width, three of them because of the DOI. I use biblatex.

My MWE looks like this

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[url=false,isbn=false,giveninits=true,maxbibnames=999]{biblatex} 
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@inproceedings{hofmann_numerical_1999,
    address = {San Francisco, USA},
    series = {{FEDSM99}-6755},
    title = {Numerical and experimental investigations on the oscillating behavior of cloud cavitation: {Part} 1 visualisation},
    booktitle = {{ASME}{/}{JSME} {Joint} {Fluids} {Engineering} {Conference}},
    author = {Hofmann, Michael and Lohrberg, H and Ludwig, G and Stoffel, B and Reboud, JL and Fortes-Patella, R},
    year = {1999}
}
@article{kravtsova_high-speed_2014,
    title = {High-speed visualization and {PIV} measurements of flows of plates and {NACA0015} hydrofoil},
    volume = {110},
    issn = {03019322},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0301932213002164},
    doi = {10.10160/j.ijmultiphaseflow.2013.12.004},
    urldate = {2018-10-23},
    journal = {International Journal of Multiphase Flow},
    author = {Kravtsova, A.Yu. and Markovich, D.M. and Pervunin, K.S. and Timoshevskiy, M.V. and Hanjali{\'c}, K.},
    year = {2014},
    pages = {1190--1220}
}
@article{jasak_high_1999,
    title = {High resolution differencing scheme}, % for arbitrarily unstructured meshes},
    volume = {31},
    issn = {02712091, 10970363},
    doi = {10.10020/(SICI)1097-01363(19990930)31:2<431::AID-FLD884>3.0.CO;2-T},
    number = {110},
    urldate = {2018-10-24},
    journal = {International Journal for Numerical Methods in Fluids},
    author = {Jasak, H. and Weller, H.G. and Gosman, A.D.},
    year = {1999},
    pages = {1431--1449}
}
@article{vogel_optical_1989,
    title = {Optical and acoustic investigations of the bubbles near a solid cute boundary},
    number = {110},
    volume = {206},
    issn = {0022-1120, 1469-7645},
    doi = {10.1017/S0022112089002314},
    urldate = {2019-11-29},
    journal = {Journal of Fluid Mechanics},
    author = {Vogel, A. and Lauterborn, W. and Timm, R.},
    year = {1989},
    pages = {299--338}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{kravtsova_high-speed_2014,hofmann_numerical_1999,vogel_optical_1989} and \cite{jasak_high_1999}.
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

According to [Achieve Linebreak in DOI](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77632/achieve-linebreak-in-doi-in-biblatex) I tried to change the penalty with the following, but without any effect:

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{badbreaks}
\addtocategory{badbreaks}{hofmann_numerical_1999,kravtsova_high-speed_2014,jasak_high_1999,vogel_optical_1989}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifcategory{badbreaks}
    {\defcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100}}
    {}}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

- Load the `xurl` package. This allows LaTeX to introduce line breaks not only in URL strings, but in doi strings as well.
- In the entry `hofmann_numerical_1999`, change the field

  ```
  booktitle = {{ASME}{/}{JSME} {Joint} {Fluids} {Engineering} {Conference}},
  ```

  to

  ```
  booktitle = {ASME\slash JSME Joint Fluids Engineering Conference},
  ```

  This allows LaTeX to introduce a line break right after the `/` ("slash") symbol. Note: it is *not* necessary to encase the words `ASME`, `JSME`, `Joint` etc in curly braces.
- Do not enter abbreviated middle initials as, say,

  ```
  Kravtsova, A.Yu. and Markovich, D.M.
  ```

  as doing so will make `biblatex/biber` (and BibTeX too, for that matter) think that there's a single first name -- and no middle initial. Do change the author information to

  ```
  Kravtsova, A. Yu. and Markovich, D. M.
  ```

  etc.

The following sample document implements these ideas. I've highlighted in yellow the line breaks which now no longer protrude into the margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % new
\usepackage[url=false,isbn=false,giveninits=true,
           maxbibnames=999]{biblatex} 
%\RequirePackage{filecontents} % not needed
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bib.bib}
@inproceedings{hofmann_numerical_1999,
    address = {San Francisco, USA},
    series = {FEDSM99-6755},
    title = {Numerical and experimental investigations on the oscillating behavior of cloud cavitation: {Part}~1 visualisation},
    booktitle = {ASME\slash JSME Joint Fluids Engineering Conference},
    author = {Hofmann, Michael and Lohrberg, H. and Ludwig, G. and Stoffel, B. and Reboud, J.L. and Fortes-Patella, R.},
    year = {1999}
}
@article{kravtsova_high-speed_2014,
    title = {High-speed visualization and {PIV} measurements of flows of plates and {NACA0015} hydrofoil},
    volume = {110},
    issn = {03019322},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0301932213002164},
    doi = {10.10160/j.ijmultiphaseflow.2013.12.004},
    urldate = {2018-10-23},
    journal = {International Journal of Multiphase Flow},
    author = {Kravtsova, A. Yu. and Markovich, D. M. and Pervunin, K. S. and Timoshevskiy, M. V. and Hanjali{\'c}, K.},
    year = {2014},
    pages = {1190--1220}
}
@article{jasak_high_1999,
    title = {High resolution differencing scheme},
    volume = {31},
    issn = {02712091, 10970363},
    doi = {10.10020/(SICI)1097-01363(19990930)31:2<431::AID-FLD884>3.0.CO;2-T},
    number = {110},
    urldate = {2018-10-24},
    journal = {International Journal for Numerical Methods in Fluids},
    author = {Jasak, H. and Weller, H. G. and Gosman, A. D.},
    year = {1999},
    pages = {1431--1449}
}
@article{vogel_optical_1989,
    title = {Optical and acoustic investigations of the bubbles near a solid cute boundary},
    number = {110},
    volume = {206},
    issn = {0022-1120, 1469-7645},
    doi = {10.1017/S0022112089002314},
    urldate = {2019-11-29},
    journal = {Journal of Fluid Mechanics},
    author = {Vogel, A. and Lauterborn, W. and Timm, R.},
    year = {1989},
    pages = {299--338}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\usepackage{xurl} % new

\begin{document}
\cite{kravtsova_high-speed_2014, hofmann_numerical_1999, vogel_optical_1989} and \cite{jasak_high_1999}.
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked perfectly for the doi entries. For the slash it works for this MWE also, but I still have to figure out how to make zotero export it as **\slash**, since zotero makes **{\textbackslash}slash** out of it. Thx also for the tip about initial names.

Comment: @Marume - Thanks for letting me know that my answer was helpful. About Zotero: If it's Zotero that created `booktitle = {{ASME}{/}{JSME} {Joint} {Fluids} {Engineering} {Conference}},`, that would be a prime example of why one shouldn't trust this tool too much. Quite apart from the issue of whether to replace `/` with `\slash`, I can simply not come up with a decent explanation of why Zotero would wrap every single word in curly braces.