# biblatex: \fullcite produces different result from bibliography entry

Tags: biblatex

I am using BibLaTeX+Biber to generate the bibliography of my thesis. I use a customised bibliography styles (based on BiBLaTeX' `numeric-comp`).

For example, here is my style definition for "inproceedings" entries, along with some redefined helper commands:

```
%load numeric-comp
\RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric-comp} %in turn that one requires standard.bbx

%This redefines the doi+eprint+url macro from standard.bbx (biblatex v1.6).
% Changes: \newblock instead of \newunit\newblock, to avoid periods after DOIs (\newunit = ". ")
% It should be prettier that way because we put DOIs and URLs on a new line (see below).
% Does not print eprint (for now)
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newblock
  %\iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
  %  {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
  %  {}%
  %\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

%Override declarations from biblatex.def (biblatex v1.6); Changes: newlines before DOI, URL, ISSN, ISBN and ISRN (+ colon in same font as label)
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \\\mkbibacro{DOI\addcolon}\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{#1}} %used to be \nolinkurl{#1} instead of #1, which is a clever trick but it I don't want the font mismatch with issn/isbn numbers (since (nolink)urls are using a different font)
    {#1}} %idem
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\\\mkbibacro{URL\addcolon}\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{isbn}{\\\mkbibacro{ISBN\addcolon}\space #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{isrn}{\\\mkbibacro{ISRN\addcolon}\space #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issn}{\\\mkbibacro{ISSN\addcolon}\space #1}

%%For (in)proceedings: only print publication date when keyword "-showpubdate" is present (to avoid repetion, date is usually already in booktitle or booksubtitle)
%%Based on publisher+location+date macro from standard.bbx (biblatex v1.6).
\newbibmacro*{publisher+location+pubdate}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \ifkeyword{-showpubdate}%
  {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{date}}%
  {}%
  \newunit}

% Inproceedings (changes: also print ISSN; disable event+venue+date, in our database this is already in the booktitle field, no time/use to split it off)
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  %%%\usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%!!! (disabled)
  %%%\newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\iffieldundef{series}% !!!
      {\printfield{volume}}% !!!
      {}% !!!
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+pubdate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}
    \newblock
    \printfield{issn}
    }
    {}%
  \newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  }
```

Now consider this entry:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Stevens2010a,
  author = {{M}atthias {S}tevens and {E}llie {D}'{H}ondt},
  title = {{C}rowdsourcing of {P}ollution {D}ata using {S}martphones},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the Workshop on Ubiquitous Crowdsourcing, held at
    Ubicomp '10 (Copenhagen, Denmark, September 26-29, 2010)},
  year = {2010},
  month = {September},
  url = {http://soft.vub.ac.be/Publications/2010/vub-tr-soft-10-15.pdf}
}
```

When I cite this somewhere in the text using `\cite{Stevens2010a}`, this produces the following entry in the bibliography:

[image: Result in bibliography (with dot, correct)]

This is what I want it to look like. Notice the "." before the newline and "URL".
But when I put an in-place citation (in the text itself) using `\fullcite{Stevens2010a}`, the result is:

[image: Full cite result (no dot, incorrect)]

Notice that here the "." is missing.

Does anyone know how I can make the `\fullcite` result look exactly like the `\cite` result? Or in other words, how I can add that "." in the `\fullcite` result?

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit. So you don't always have to use `<code>`. Bigger blocks of code simply indent by 4 spaces instead of writing `<code>` and `<pre>` (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks).

Comment: In its core, the question simply seems to ask how to insert a bibtex entry within the document in the same way as it appears in the references list. Notably, biber is used as backend. This very question (and a simple solution) is also discussed here [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135930/use-bibentry-with-biblatex] and here [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126226/how-do-i-instruct-fullcite-to-use-maxbibnames-rather-than-maxcitenames]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like bibliography entries and `\footfullcite`, `\fullcite` is generated by the bibliography driver. The only difference is that `\fullcite` doesn't set `\finentrypunct`.

You can apply edits to the `finentry` bibliography macro to resolve this difference. See the code below for a demonstration. I've also illustrated another approach to [line-breaking before `doi`/`url`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29802/4483) and use of [the xpatch package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40705/4483).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newtoggle{bbx:urlbreak}

% Set \finentrypunct unless the entry ends with an URL
\xpretobibmacro{finentry}
  {\iftoggle{bbx:urlbreak}
     {\nopunct}
     {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcitation} and not test {\iffootnote} }
        {\finentrypunct}
        {}}%
   \global\togglefalse{bbx:urlbreak}}
  {}{}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:parunit}{%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \clearlist{pageref}%
  \setunit{%
    \adddot\par\noindent\nobreak%
    \global\toggletrue{bbx:urlbreak}}}

% Insert linebreak before printing URLs
\xpretobibmacro{doi+eprint+url}{\usebibmacro{bbx:parunit}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{url+urldate}{\usebibmacro{bbx:parunit}}{}{}

% Suppress eprint
\xpretobibdriver{inproceedings}{\clearfield{eprint}}{}{}

% Suppress date, event data
\renewbibmacro*{date}{\ifkeyword{-showdate}{}{\printdate}}
\renewbibmacro{event+venue+date}{}

% Print ISSN
\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}
  {\printfield{isbn}}
  {\printfield{isbn}\newunit\newblock\printfield{issn}}
  {}{}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{stevens,
  author = {Matthias Stevens and Ellie D'Hondt},
  title = {Crowdsourcing of Pollution Data using Smartphones},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the Workshop on Ubiquitous Crowdsourcing, held at
    Ubicomp '10 (Copenhagen, Denmark, September 26-29, 2010)},
  keywords = {-showdate},
  year = {2010},
  month = {9},
  url = {http://soft.vub.ac.be/Publications/2010/vub-tr-soft-10-15.pdf}}
@INPROCEEDINGS{test,
  author = {John Doe and Jane Doe},
  title = {Seminar Title},
  booktitle = {Proceedings Title},
  year = {2010},
  month = {12},
  isbn = {1234},
  issn = {5678},
  eprint = {http://eprint.com}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
\fullcite{test} \\
\fullcite{stevens} \\
Filler text.\footfullcite{test}
More filler text.\footfullcite{stevens}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However, would this xpatch stuff also work if I put in my bbx (biblatex bibliography style) file? Or does this only work in tex/cls?

Comment: @Matthias It should work provided that the patching commands come after `\RequirePackage{xpatch}` and the bibmacro/driver definitions.

Answer (score 9):

Though not as extensive as Audrey's helpful answer, I found solution that worked for my needs (I only wanted to change the number of authors in the citation). Full credit should go to the github user aboruvka who provided an answer while responding to a biblatex [issue](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/61) on github. Below is the code copied from his/her post. My addition of a period after `{\thefield{entrytype}}` is more of a hack than a generic solution.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\defcounter{minnames}{6}%
      \defcounter{maxnames}{6}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}.}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

After adding this to the preamble, my `\fullcite` references appear the same as they would in my bibliography.