# Extending an existing BibLaTeX entry type or creating a new entry type?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I need to make one minor modification to the `manual` entry type of BibLaTex. The modification is to add one field and print that field instead of the `version` field if it has been set in the entry. My question is whether I should extend the existing `manual` type or create a new entry type like `extmanual`. I expect both variants to work, but I want to know what is considered best practice by the community.

As an aside: the `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{manual}` in `standard.bbx` uses `\printfield{version}` instead of e.g. `\usebibmacro{version}`, so I guess I won't be able to cleanly change the existing `manual` driver anyway and I will have to re(declare) the complete driver for both variants--- is that correct?
(It feels wrong to change `\DeclareFieldFormat{version}{...}` for my needs, if that is even possible.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For small modifications of what is essential still the same data type I would just modify the driver (or the relevant bibmacros, if possible since that usually involves less code) and would not define a new entry type. But if the work is of an essentially different type than what `@manual` normally represents and you intend to cite more works of this type, a new driver might still make sense.

From the problem description and the suggested new name `@extmanual` I'm guessing we are talking about the first case, in which I would just modify the driver.

---

You can use [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch/)'s `\xpatchbibdriver` to patch the bibdriver without having to copy its definition completely (as shown for example in [biblatex: \fullcite produces different result from bibliography entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43196/35864)). See also [Biblatex's bibmacros, bibliography drivers, formats - patch or redefine?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409091/35864).

The following patch will add the `edition` field after the `version` for `@misc` entries

```
\xpatchbibdriver{misc}
  {\printfield{version}}
  {\printfield{version}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \printfield{edition}}
  {}{}
```

*edit*: Originally I patched the `@manual` driver here to stay closer to the question, but I just realised that `@manual` already prints `edition` even without a patch, so that would have been a pointless exercise.