# biblatex and new line for Title, and all entries in general

Tags: biblatex, formatting, line-breaking

I want to create a Bibliography that is a little more readable, meaning, for a single bibliography entry everything should start on a new line.
Since the document will not be printed, nor submitted to any journal, this should be allowed :-)

Well I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29802/biblatex-and-new-line-for-doi-url-and-eprint), which basically solves the problem for some,
However, the biblatex.def is a little too complicated for my tastes, and I'm at a loss how to translate this into a solution that I like.

Basically what I want is this:

```
First Author, Second Author, And So Forth,
The title of the work,
DOI for example,
And all the other stuff continues on like this,
....
```

Instead of the usual random linebreaks and in general hard to read stuff that looks somewhat like this

```
First Author, Second Author, And So Forth, The title of
the work, DOI for example, And all the other stuff 
continues on like this, ....
```

I guess it should be possible to insert a linebreak before any type of element whatsoever, instead of manually doing it for each element. (Although that would be preferable for some people, if they only need it for some elements)
In any case, I don't know which elements those are, because there are a lot of elements named "title" and "author" in biblatex.def.

Comment: `block=par` does something close to this, is that sufficient? I.e. `\usepackage[block=par]{biblatex}`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for, it does what I want for the full references at the end, but does not change the appearance of eventual footnotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`block=par` does this for the bibliography at least.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[block=par]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```